# How to get selected privacy option before posting to feed?

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I'm using Facebook SDK (3.14.1) for Android.

Before publishing something to the users feed, I ask for "publish_actions" permission which results in this screen:

[image: privacy question]

with these options:

[image: privacy question options]

After acquiring the permission, I prepare and execute a `RequestBatch` to post to `/me/feed` of the user.

**The question is**: how can I know which privacy option the user has selected?

Comment: May I ask why it matter? Shouldn't the user be allowed to choose what they want?

Comment: Indeed. I just want to know what they have chosen, analytics-wise.

Comment: Without better knowledge I wouldn't be surprised if these analytics were available for FB only.